# GregorianCalendar

Tags: java, datetime

I have to create a class `Data` with dates and there should be some methods and constructor. Maybe some method can be done in another way, especially the method `wichIsEarlier`, because I made it `static` and I'm not really sure about it. Please take a look on this class and say what is good and what is bad. Is it better to use class `Calendar` than `GregorianCalendar`? Where should I throw an exception?

```
class Data {
    GregorianCalendar gcalendar = new GregorianCalendar();

    Data(GregorianCalendar x) {
        gcalendar = x;
    }

    public boolean czyPrzestepny() {

        boolean rr = false;
        if (gcalendar.isLeapYear(gcalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR))) {
            rr = true;
        } else {
            rr = false;
        }
        return rr;
    }

    public int ileDniWMiesiacu() {
        int dni = 0;
        switch (gcalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)) {
        case 0:
        case 2:
        case 4:
        case 6:
        case 7:
        case 9:
        case 11:
            dni = 31;
            break;
        case 3:
        case 5:
        case 8:
        case 10:
            dni = 30;
            break;
        case 1:
            dni = 28;
            dni = 29;
            break;
        }
        return dni;
    }

    static String wichIsEarlier(GregorianCalendar y, GregorianCalendar gcalendar) {
        int yyear = y.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int ymonth = y.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int ydate = y.get(Calendar.DATE);
        int year = gcalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = gcalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = gcalendar.get(Calendar.DATE);
        String re = "";
        if (yyear > year)
            re = "moja data nie jest wczesniejsza od teraz";
        else if (yyear < year)
            re = " jest wczesniejsze";
        else if (ymonth < month)
            re = " jest wczesniejsze";
        else if (ymonth > month)
            re = " nie jest wczesniejsze";
        else if (ydate > day)
            re = "  nie jest wczesniejsze";
        else if (ydate < day)
            re = " jest wczesniejsze";
        return re;
    }

    public void changeDate(GregorianCalendar y) {
        gcalendar = y;
    }

    public String toString() {
        String months[] = { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "Mai", "June", "July", "Aug", "Sep", "Okt",
                "Nov", "Dec" };
        String str = "";
        str = "Data: " + gcalendar.get(Calendar.DATE) + " " + months[gcalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)]
                + " " + gcalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        return str;
    }
}

public class Datum {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
        GregorianCalendar yycal = new GregorianCalendar(1994, 0, 15);
        Data dt = new Data(gc);
        System.out.println("czy Przestepny " + dt.czyPrzestepny());
        System.out.println("ile dni w miesiacu " + dt.ileDniWMiesiacu());
        System.out.println("ktore jest wczesniejsze " + Data.wichIsEalier(gc, yycal));
        System.out.println(dt.toString());
        dt.changeDate(yycal);
        System.out.println(dt.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: First thing, some of your methods name don't seems to be in English. You should change those because I have no idea what `ileDniWMiesiacu` is suppose to do. This will help to have a better review in my opinion!

Comment: replace also  case 1: in default:, and modify the numbers like 6 (june) is a 30 days month.

Comment: month in GregorianCalender is counting from 0 so 6 is July and it is 31

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are making a class which behaves like [`GregorianCalendar class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) so you can always check the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/GregorianCalendar.java). But if it is an assignment try to do it yourself first and compare your program to see how the creators choose the logic and building pattern.

- ```
  GregorianCalendar gcalendar = new GregorianCalendar(); // unnecessary
  ```

  make it inside the constructor and make `gcalendar` a private field.
- I don't know your language so try to post the code in english as far as possible. Your method names such as `czyPrzestepny`, `ileDniWMiesiacu` is hard to understand. You can also use Javadoc.

> Is it better to use class Calendar than GregorianCalendar?

[Yes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10177523/using-superclass-to-initialise-a-subclass-object-java). Cause abstraction and [code re usability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9852831/polymorphism-why-use-list-list-new-arraylist-instead-of-arraylist-list-n?lq=1) are some main parts of OOP language.

- `wichIsEalier` should be `isBefore` and non-static and return boolean similar to [`Calendar.before()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#before%28java.lang.Object%29).

Answer (score 5):

As Marc-Andre mentioned, you should really use English for your methods and classes, so that we can review better.

Still, I am fairly certain that

```
public  boolean czyPrzestepny(){
    boolean rr = false;
    if(gcalendar.isLeapYear(gcalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR))){
        rr=true;
    }
    else{
       rr=false;
    }
    return rr;
}
```

could probably written as

```
public boolean isLeapYear()
{
  return gcalendar.isLeapYear(gcalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR))
}
```

The following code seems, wrong, you probably forgot to check for leap year?

> ```
>        case 1:
>        dni = 28;dni= 29;
> ```

Also, `wichIsEalier` should be `wichIsEarlier`

Also, gcalendar does not follow proper lowerCamelCase, and Data is just too ambiguous as a class name.

Finally, for getting the month name in toString, you could just call `gcalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH).` and take the first 3 characters. Free I18N is good.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the things I would question in a code review:

1. Not sure what the year, month, and day members are for.  If you want to be able to get those values from the gcalendar, why not just get them from the gcalendar?  What you are trying to do there doesn't make much sense to me.
2. Your naming convention does not really follow standards.  I don't know what a "gcalendar" is, but I know what a "usersBirthDay" is or a "purchaseDate" is.  I would consider renaming your variables and methods...they should be "self documenting".
3. You are not following good Java Bean patterns.  First, your member variables should be marked private, or at least protected.  Second, you need to have getters/setters that are named "get" and/or "set" for the members, depending on if the value should be read/write accessible.  Methods that return a boolean are typically named "is" instead of "get, for example "isCzyPrzestepny()".
4. None of your methods are marked as public, private, or protected.  You should specify your security specifically.
5. No JavaDoc at all (this could simply be because you took it out to post, but you should have JavaDoc on your public methods, constructors, etc.
6. Use "Calendar" instead of "GregorianCalendar".  The reason we have interfaces and abstract classes is so we can generalize the code to work with any type of that object.  General good architecture says you should always reference objects by the least specific you can.  In this case, I don't see any reason to not reference Calendar.
7. Calendar has methods to determine if one Calendar is before() or after() the other.  You should be using those, and not rolling your own.
8. You asked if you can check the Calendar in the constructor?  Sure.  What I would recommend is checking the Calendar passed in the constructor IN the constructor, and throwing an exception if it doesn't pass the test.  The exception can be either an Exception (requires the calling code to try/catch or rethrow it) or a RuntimeException (does not require the calling code to try/catch or rethrow it, but will make the program halt if it doesn't), and you can either use one of the off-the-shelf ones in the API or create a custom exception.  I usually prefer to create my own custom Exceptions as to make troubleshooting easier.